# Scrolling element correspond scrolling window

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I want ask to you "How to create scrolling element correspond with scrolling window."

If window get end of scroll, that element can be scrolling down.
And if window get start of scroll, that element can be scrolling up.

I was try to make that but didn't solved.

Here is my code :

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(event) {
        var lengthScrollWindow = $(this)[0].scrollTop;
        if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
            lengthScrollWindow -= 40;
            $('.main_profile').animate({scrollTop: lengthScrollWindow},700);
        }
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            lengthScrollWindow += 40;
            $('.main_profile').animate({scrollTop: lengthScrollWindow},700);
        }
    });
```

Here is my Fiddle :

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/el_mahbub/23e6ncg9/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is that you are trying to animate .main_profile using the wrong quantity.  I can't really tell what you are trying to do, but if you want to move .main_profile up when you scroll up and down when you scroll down you could animate it like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
      var lastScrollTop = 0;
      $(".main_profile").scroll(function(event) {


        var top = 40;
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st < lastScrollTop) {
       top -= 40;
          $(".main_profile").animate({
            top: top + "px"
          }, 1);


        } else if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      top += 40;
          $(".main_profile").animate({
            top: top + "px"
          }, 1);


        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
      });

    });
```

Comment: You not understand what is my problem. Also i was tring your code like this and not work : var lastScrollTop = 0;
      $(window).scroll(function(event) {
       var top = 40;
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st < lastScrollTop) {
       top -= 40;
          $(".main_profile").animate({
            top: top + "px"
          }, 1);


        } else if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      top += 40;
          $(".main_profile").animate({
            top: top + "px"
          }, 1);


        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
      });

Comment: Could you explain it differently?  Even in your own language then I can use Google translate or something.

Comment: This is my own languange that you want to translate : Bagaimana cara membuat scrolling elemen sesuai window yang di scroll ? Jadi ketika scroll window(jendela browser) ke atas maka elemen itu di gulir/scroll ke atas, ketika window(jendela browser) di scroll ke bawah maka elemen tadi juga di scroll ke bawah.

Comment: I see.  I think what you want is a fixed element.  In css you can define `position: fixed` then set `left: 0;` and `top: 0` then it should scroll with the window.  If you want the element to scroll 1% of the window height for every 1% of the document height then you are in the same position I am in and you can see my question and how I partially accomplished it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051355/translate-html-element-down-page-height-relative-to-document-height).

Comment: You could even `+=` a distance from the top on every scroll using the `top:` attribute like `var dHeight = $(document).height() / 100;` then `$('.main_profile').css({top: (x += dHeight) + "%"});`.  I can't test it right now but I will later if you haven't already figured it out.

Comment: All right, if that element not have load function as demo page from bootstrap about affix plugin, but my element have load function with scrolling down to load more data. Anything thank you.